# How to schedule a piece of code to run at a specific time, and repeat daily?

Tags: ios, swift, watchkit, apple-watch

I'm new to WatchKit development. I've been wanting to create a simple app that requires the ability to display a message at a certain time of day, and repeat this process daily.

I've tried to use NSTimer but once I open another app, the message is no longer shown. I don't know if this is the correct way to do it.

I would like some general insight on what ways I can approach this.

Edit: If possible, I prefer that it can work without relying on the iPhone's notification architecture. I wonder how the built-in Timer app works.

Edit 2: NSTimer seems like the way to go, the reason the message wasn't shown has more to do with the user interface system.

Comment: use NSTIMER() and NSCALENDER for WEEKDAYS

Comment: You can schedule a UILocalNotification with a repeat interval. It will be displayed on the phone or watch depending on what iOS detects is the active device

Comment: What did you decide on here?